# Visualforce Error: Unknown property 'Store__cStandardController.Store

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, console, custom-console-components

I am trying to design a console where the first block of it contains a custom object "Store" something similar to Account. I want a list of Associates(custom object similar to contacts) in the same section of the block.

Could anyone give me the idea for a vf page of the list of associates on the store object:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Store__C">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}!">
            We are viewing the Associates for this <b>{!Store__C.name}</b> Store.  
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Associates">
             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Store__C}" var="Ass">
                  <apex:column value="{!Ass.Name}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!Ass.Lastname}"/><apex:column value="{!Ass.Phone}"/
             </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the relationship name from Store__c to Associate__c is called Associates, then the line you need is

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Store__c.Associates__r}" var="Ass">
```

N.B. use of an iterator `ass` is not best practice for US/UK audiences - try `assoc`

Comment: Yeah I was going to say...not the most professional use of abbreviation.

Comment: Hello Adrian and Cropredy, I did think of coming up something other than ass. Couldn't know much of the limitations. I will try this code and will let you know how it goes.